# Getting Json from API to use in Gmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i would use this API Service to learn more on Javascript / Jquery.

I need to fetch the JSON to reutilize in Gmap but i don't know how modify function to have my goal.

Could you help me?

Thank you very much!

Demo => http://jsfiddle.net/rpC3n/

LINK Api: http://api.citybik.es/

Code =>

```
$.getJSON('http://api.citybik.es/networks.json', function (data) {
$.each(data.city) {
    $('#output').append(data.city);
}
});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a cross domain request, you need to use JSONP.

so your jQuery would look like:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://api.citybik.es/networks.json',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data,function(){
            console.log(this);
            //do your gmap stuff here
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log("Error",arguments);
    }
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rpC3n/1/ (check your console to see what your returned data looks like)